# How to access properties that are in an Inherited UserControl in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I created an `UserControl` that consists of a `TextBox` and a `Label` controls. I created another `UserContol` that inherits the first, on which I added a `Button`. The difficult that I’m experiencing is that I can’t access directly from secondary `UserControl` properties like `TextBox.Text` that are in the primary `UserControl`. Is there a easy way to access properties from the primary `UserControl` or the only way is to create a public methods, like a “GetText()”, where I return the TextBox.Text property?

Comment: Can you share your component code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about WPF.

Xaml view you can use `x:FieldModifier="Public"`

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" x:FieldModifier="Public" />
```

Note that accessing inner controls is not best practise, your code should not care what controls view contains. If you want for example make button disabled create property in code behind and bind buttons IsEnabled to that property instead